# The verb [手伝]{てつだ}う, does it use the particle に?

Tags: grammar, particles, verbs, transitivity

For example, if I want to say "I helped my uncle yesterday", how would I say it?

> 昨日私のおじさん**に**てつだいました。

Or, I would just use the particle を.

> 昨日私のおじさん**を**てつだいました。

Answer (score 2):

'昨日私のおじさんをてつだいました' is the correct one.

- Xをてつだいました when X is the object of 'help'
- 'にてつだいました' is possible as a sequence in other cases. See https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10135898565

Also as a side note, '昨日おじさんをてつだいました' would be more usual (without '私の') if the helper is 'I'.

Comment: ありがとうございました。とても便利ですよ。